# plotting a piecewise function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot a piecewise function in mathematica. I used the following code:

[image: Figure 1]

But ended up with a blank plot. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: don't know where my first comment went. The things you see in blue are undefined symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state the variable epsilon0. Currently:

```
p[r_] := Piecewise[{{2/(\[Epsilon]0*r) + (3 r^2)/\[Epsilon]0, 
0 <= r <= 1}, {4 r/\[Epsilon]0, 1 <= r <= 2}, {16/(\[Epsilon]0*r),
 r >= 2}}]
Plot[p[r] /. \[Epsilon]0 -> 1, {r, 0, 4}, ExclusionsStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, Blue}]
```

So, using

```
p[r] /. \[Epsilon]0 -> 1
```

you can calculate function p[r] for any value of [Epsilon]0. In this example for 1.